# error: exportArchive: Bundle “Runner.app” does not specify a platform identifier in its Info.plist

Tags: ios, flutter, fastlane, xcode14

A few days ago, I upgraded Xcode to version 14.2. When using Fastlane to package, I encountered the following error message: "error: exportArchive: Bundle ‘Runner.app’ does not specify a platform identifier in its Info.plist. ipatool failed with an exception: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `end_with?’ for nil:NilClass>". Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you.

It’s quite strange. When the export_method is set to "app-store", there is no problem with the export. However, if it is set to "ad-hoc", this error occurs.